# Are all manifolds in $\mathbb R^n$ homeomorphic to a smooth manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

My question is whether all manifolds that can be embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ are homeomorphic to a smooth manifold?

I know that every smooth manifold can be triangulated which I think is a result of Whitehead and I think every manifold in $\mathbb R^n$ can be triangulated so this lends plausibility I think. (If the dimension 4 E8 manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ then we have a counterexample but I'm not sure if it can be. All manifolds of dimension up to 3 can be triangulated).

I appreciate if this is a basic question but it doesn't seem to be spelt out explicitly anywhere. Most textbooks define a manifold and then a smooth manifold but don't say in which cases these concepts may be equivalent.

Comment: *Any* manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$, see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34658/30186)

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you. Any chance you can add your response as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is negative. As you observe yourself, if we allow abstract manifolds, then the E8 manifold provides a counterexample. However, it turns out that *any* abstract manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb R^n$ for a suitable $n$ (for instance, twice the dimension plus one, see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34658/30186)), so in particular the E8 manifold is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ (for $n=9$) which is not homeomorphic to a smooth manifold.

Comment: Thank you. It's perhaps worth noting that the result is trivially true for manifolds of dimension 1,2 and 3 simply because all manifolds in these lower dimensions have a unique differential and hence smooth structure.

Comment: This is Nash embedding theorem

Comment: @debabratachakraborty Nash embedding theorem concerns Riemannian manifolds, which ought to be $C^1$ for the Riemannian structure to even make sense.

Comment: @IvanMeir I don't think one can call the uniqueness of smooth structures on three  manifolds "trivial". I think it is the main result of an influential Annals paper.

Comment: @Spiritofperpetualnegation I meant that my result in dims 1,2 and 3 was a trivial deduction from the proven fact that all manifolds in these dimensions have smooth structure.